# Segue of tableViewController in header collectionViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uicollectionview

Pls help me with my code, I'm newbie in programming, but I understand that my variable takes a nil. And where I can not make out.
P.S. My English is not good, but i study. :)

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

var file: File!

var files: [File] = [File(name: "name1", address: "address1", image: ""), File(name: "name2", address: "address2", image: "")]

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
if let dvc = segue.destination as? CollectionViewController {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row
    if indexPath == nil {
        dvc.files2 = files[indexPath!]
    } else {
        print("error")
    }
  }
}


class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

var files2: File!

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "Header", for: indexPath) as! Header

header.nameLabel.text = files2!.name
header.addressLabel.text = "address"

return header
}
```

Comment: If it helps - [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: You need to provide more information about your problem. Which line of code is causing your issue? What is the error?

Comment: Which variable is nil from your code give above?

Comment: When i start app and i'll do transition on collectionViewController i get an error as on a screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wnllwyhs5xkwiw0/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-07-09%2023.37.51.png?dl=0